# Solr not showing the indexed items count

Tags: tomcat, solr, drupal-7, indexing

I am using Solr and Tomcat with Drupal. When I create a Solr server, it works fine. When I index the items using the Solr Server it says: There are 0 items indexed on the server for this index. (More information).

Did anyone face the same issues earlier?

I am getting below warnings:

```
15:38:33
WARN
SolrResourceLoader
Can't find (or read) directory to add to classloader: ../../../contrib/extraction/lib (resolved as: /usr/local/tomcat/solr/drupal/../../../contrib/extraction/lib).
15:38:33
WARN
SolrResourceLoader
Can't find (or read) directory to add to classloader: ../../../dist/ (resolved as: /usr/local/tomcat/solr/drupal/../../../dist).
15:38:33
WARN
SolrResourceLoader
Can't find (or read) directory to add to classloader: ../../../contrib/clustering/lib/ (resolved as: /usr/local/tomcat/solr/drupal/../../../contrib/clustering/lib).
15:38:33
WARN
SolrResourceLoader
Can't find (or read) directory to add to classloader: ../../../dist/ (resolved as: /usr/local/tomcat/solr/drupal/../../../dist).
15:38:33
WARN
SolrResourceLoader
Can't find (or read) directory to add to classloader: ../../../contrib/langid/lib/ (resolved as: /usr/local/tomcat/solr/drupal/../../../contrib/langid/lib).
15:38:33
WARN
SolrResourceLoader
Can't find (or read) directory to add to classloader: ../../../dist/ (resolved as: /usr/local/tomcat/solr/drupal/../../../dist).
15:38:33
WARN
SolrResourceLoader
Can't find (or read) directory to add to classloader: ../../../contrib/velocity/lib (resolved as: /usr/local/tomcat/solr/drupal/../../../contrib/velocity/lib).
15:38:33
WARN
SolrResourceLoader
Can't find (or read) directory to add to classloader: ../../../dist/ (resolved as: /usr/local/tomcat/solr/drupal/../../../dist).
15:38:33
WARN
Config
XML parse warning in "solrres:/schema.xml",​ line 337,​ column 88: Include 操作失败,​ 并还原为 fallback。以 XML (href='schema_extra_types.xml') 格式读取文件时出现资源错误。原因: Can't find resource 'schema_extra_types.xml' in classpath or '/usr/local/tomcat/solr/drupal/conf'
15:38:33
WARN
Config
XML parse warning in "solrres:/schema.xml",​ line 532,​ column 89: Include 操作失败,​ 并还原为 fallback。以 XML (href='schema_extra_fields.xml') 格式读取文件时出现资源错误。原因: Can't find resource 'schema_extra_fields.xml' in classpath or '/usr/local/tomcat/solr/drupal/conf'
15:38:33
WARN
SolrResourceLoader
Solr loaded a deprecated plugin/analysis class [solr.JsonUpdateRequestHandler]. Please consult documentation how to replace it accordingly.
15:38:33
WARN
SolrResourceLoader
Solr loaded a deprecated plugin/analysis class [solr.CSVRequestHandler]. Please consult documentation how to replace it accordingly.
16:46:29
ERROR
SolrCore
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Invalid Number: Vatican
```

Comment: I'd start by looking for the reason why this is outputed in the log: "Invalid Number: Vatican". Could it be that Solr is configured with a numerical filedType for the field, and thus it throws an error when trying to create such a document (and that possibly the error is quietly written to the log) ?

Comment: No Solr is configured correctly.I am able to view the Solr admin and perform server connection

Comment: Agreed, but what I was saying is that the document you send over to Solr is not valid (inproper, non-numerical value for numerical field)...

Comment: How can I verify that

Comment: Try http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler to test your Solr server, that it accept your docs